# CSS triangle on edge of container ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, sass

I have a table and I made a class that puts a triangle on the bottom edge of the header cell. See here

[image]

It works perfect in everything except ie8. From reading online I found that ie8 supports these triangles but when I try to position it outside of the cell it disappears.

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

SASS:

```
.rds-promo-header{
    color: #e3c02f !important;
    position:relative;
    &:before{
        content:" ";
        width: 0; 
        height: 0; 
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;       
        border-top: 10px solid pink;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 47%;
    }
}

.ie8 .rds-promo-header:before{

}
```

On ie8 it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: don't think ie8 handles relative positioning on a td so you won't be able to absolutely position anything in it properly

Comment: I made a ie8 specific class to put on the cell directly under the promo-header cell which gives it the triangle.

Comment: Does ie8 default to `overflow: hidden`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's z-index.

```
.rds-promo-header {
    width 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: navy;
    color: #e3c02f !important;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;

    & + & {
        background-color: gray;
    }
}

.arrow {
    z-index: 9999;
    &:before {
        content:" ";
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-top: 10px solid navy;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -10px;
        left: 47%;
    }

    & + &:before {
        border-top: 10px solid gray;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0226xop/5/)

[Image via BrowserStack Win7 IE8](http://cl.ly/image/0z081p0Y3Q2A/win7_ie_8.0.png)